# The video on the image target is darker when played on AR camera than the original video clip

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, video-player

I am using Unity to create an AR interaction and have a video clip placed on top of my target image and in a quad. It plays correctly but only the colors are darker, almost like an overlay on the video.

I have tried removing the mesh render settings.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIqUn.png)

Comment: What are the rest of the Video Player settings (cut off on the screenshot)?  Are you using a lit or unlit material?